# React handle response()->download server response

Tags: javascript, ajax, laravel-excel

I use Laravel-Excel to export eloquent collection to .xls file and store it in server. And, I return laravel's download response type, namely **response()->download($filePath)**.

Simple version of server code:

```
function getExportToFile($pId){      
  $data = array(
    array('data1', 'data2'),
    array('data3', 'data4')
  );


  Excel::create('strings', function($excel) use($data) {
    $excel->sheet('Sheetname', function($sheet) use($data) {
        $sheet->fromArray($data);
    });
  })->store('xls');

  return response()->download(storage_path('exports/strings.xls'));}
```

Client side action handler:

```
if(a == Actions.ExportTofile)
  {
     return new Promise( function(resolve,reject)
     {
        $.get('/project/export-to-file/' + p1.id).then(
           function(a)
           {
              resolve();
           }
        );
     });
  }
```

I understand that my client side should be changed in order to handle the download response but I dont know how to change it. How can I make the downloading process to start?

Any helps would be appreciated.